# Wicket: Get URL from browser

Tags: java, wicket

I need to retrieve URL from current Web page opened in Firefox by using Wicket. Can somebody tell  me how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to query the underlying [HTTPServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html):

```
public class DummyPage extends WebPage{

    private String getRequestUrl(){
        // this is a wicket-specific request interface
        final Request request = getRequest();
        if(request instanceof WebRequest){
            final WebRequest wr = (WebRequest) request;
            // but this is the real thing
            final HttpServletRequest hsr = wr.getHttpServletRequest();
            String reqUrl = hsr.getRequestURL().toString();
            final String queryString = hsr.getQueryString();
            if(queryString != null){
                reqUrl += "?" + queryString;
            }
            return reqUrl;
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

**Reference:**

- (Wicket) [Component.getRequest()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getRequest%28%29)
- (Wicket) [Request](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Request.html)
- (Wicket) [WebRequest](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebRequest.html)
- (Servlet API) [HTTPServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Answer (score 8):

To get the current page's url use the webrequest and UrlRenderer:

```
Url url = ((WebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest()).getUrl();
String fullUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution from Sean Patrick Floyd seems to be obsolete for wicket 1.5

If using wicket 1.5 (or above I guess) here is the solution:

```
RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(
    Url.parse(urlFor(MyPage.class,null).toString()));
```

**Reference**:

[Getting a url for display](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Getting+a+url+for+display)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you want, this may not be possible. There is a short guide [here in the Wicket wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/getting-a-url-for-display.html), but it has some caveats, notably that it only returns a relative URL in versions of Wicket after 1.3. That said, the method used is

```
String url = urlFor("pageMapName", MyPage.class, new PageParameters("foo=bar"));
```

If you go with the wiki's alternate method — the one involving the form — be warned: `getPage()` is [not part of Wicket's public API](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/index.html?org/apache/wicket/Session.html#getPage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

This works. I'm using wicket 1.5;

new URL(RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(
                              Url.parse(urlFor(HomePage.class,null).toString()))).**getAuthority()**;

Example: http://example.com:80/a_long_path/

getAuthproty() will return example.com:80

getHost() will return example.com.